# Making TortoiseSVN ready for dummies

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I have some guys in my project who will never ever learn SVN, but I want them to use it anyway. So is there an option to make TortoiseSVN just

- automatically delete all missing files (that were under verison control but deleted)
- automatically add all new files (that are not yet under version control)

I think you can write local client hooks for TortoiseSVN, but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: What kind of project is this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Missing files will be automatically listed when you commit (or, better, `check for modifications`)
2. I don't think it's possible to add new files completely automatically, but the `check for modifications` dialog will detect and list them as well, and makes them dead easy to add.

Tortoise's modifications dialog really is a great tool. Tell your guys to have that open all the time and refresh it frequently, and it will work out all right. Also check out the "changesets" feature that makes sorting changes into separate commits a real breeze.

Comment: Yeah, the modifications dialog is actually great, but it's a fairly too complex tool for ordinary computer users. They simply don't get the point about "modified" or "deleted" or "unversioned" files.

Comment: @nils I see. I don't think you will get around educating them then  - version control doesn't really get any easier than SVN and Tortoise..... At least, I don't know anything more easy.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what you want is to mount your Subversion project as a [WebDAV](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.webdav.basic.html) folder, and use [autoversioning](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.webdav.autoversioning.html) to handle the commits?  In that case, your users don't need to know anything about Subversion.

Windows does have WebDAV support built in, in the form of "Web Folders", but it is a little buggy.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Hey, this is a great idea! Totally forgot about WebDAV. +1.

Comment: Yes, I actually love autoversioning, but as you said, WebDAV is a bit buggy and slow. Having a local checkout with autoversioning would just be great - and some years ago I started programming such a feature (but didn't finish it)

Comment: @nils: Just to clarify: WebDAV isn't buggy, it's Microsoft's implementation of it that is troublesome.  You might want to try a third-party WebDAV client like [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/winindex.html) to see if that does any better.